# Sidekiq retry only in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jobs, sidekiq

I have about a dozen sidekiq worker objects that are queued up periodically via the clockwork gem (roughly 10,000 jobs a day - not a ton).  Everything is working great.

The issue is that while developing I'm prone to making mistakes in my code.  If I leave the `retry` option out of the equation, those failed jobs will continue to try and try, flooding my development sidekiq logs with failures.

I want to know if I can either turn off `retry` in development mode or perhaps clear all jobs if I kill sidekiq locally (I'm thinking of the way database-cleaner works in testing).  I've read over [error handling](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling) but don't really see my topic covered.

for example:

```
class DailyActivityWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    #make some call to an API
    #save parts of that call to the database
  end
end
```

I know I can add this inside every worker but that seems redundant

```
  sidekiq_options retry: false if Rails.env.development?
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set them in one place by modifying the default worker options:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#workers

For example, `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  Sidekiq.default_worker_options = { retry: false }
end
```